# Where did  originate from?

Tags: meaning, etymology

I was looking up the Vietnamese word cửa hàng. Hàng Seems fairly straight forward as it used to be written with the Chinese character 行 and pronunciation is quite similar also. Cửa is not as simple; it seems to be a form of  (or perhaps ) but  there is very little info about it.

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%F0%A8%B7%B6) does say that it is a:

> Han character

举 and 门 makes me think that it's got something to do with being 'open' (i.e.: for business) but I'm not sure.

Any ideas?

Comment: `Wiktionary does say that it is a Han character` This definition of "Han character" is very broad, and coincides with the first paragraph in  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_characters. I suppose, if *kokuji* and *gukja* are "Han characters", then there is no reason for *Chữ Nôm* and *Sawndip* not to be "Han characters". Well,  and  are definitely *Chữ Nôm*, and not a "Chinese" "Han character".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Vietnamese word for *shop* is **cửa hàng**.

**Cửa** is not [Sino-Vietnamese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sino-Vietnamese_vocabulary), but a [Vietic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vietic_languages) morpheme. IF (and that's a big IF) **cửa** in **cửa hàng** means *door*, then **cửa** can be represented by「」, which just means *door*, and「舉」is not part of the meaning of **cửa**.

> 「」or「」(**cửa**) is made up of semantic「門」(*door*) and phonetic「舉」(**cử**).

---

Chinese has a similar word:「門市」, which is *the front of a store*.